# Is there a compound or element with properties similar to H2O?

Tags: elements, chemistry-in-fiction

Is there an existing compound or element with properties similar to H2O? 
( Liquid, non toxic, stable, and with a clear / blue coloration )  I would expect that any such element or compound would not exist in a stable form, however, I curious to see whether something similar may exist.

I need this for a fictional piece I am working on as a substance from an alien planet.

Comment: Saturn's moon Titan has [lakes of liquid hydrocarbons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Titan).

Comment: Drinkable by what/whom? Anyway ammonia  could be a possibility (but personally I don't really believe it fits your criteria), see http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/what-would-an-ammonia-based-world-look-like for more thoughts.

Comment: Why do you need real chemistry? You can make up any liquid you want, just call it a different name.

Comment: I've just seen this question on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Im-trying-to-create-a-made-up-planet-How-can-I-create-new-elements